# github api does not return my post-receive web hook

Tags: github, githooks, github-api

I have manually added a web hook to my repository, but when I query the repository using the API I get

```
{
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

what is wrong?

the url: https://api.github.com/repos/akonsu/kamyanov-art.com/hooks/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't put the extra '`/`' at the end.
That will get you an message "`Not Found`" every time, authenticated or not.

Second, to add to Ivan's answer, you need to authenticate to access that information about a repo (public or private).

As mentioned in the "[API Getting Started](http://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#repositories)" page:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

{
    "message": "Not Found"
}
```

Oh noes! Where did it go?
If you’re a grizzled HTTP user, you might expect a 403 instead.
**Since we don’t want to leak information about private repositories, the GitHub API returns a 404 in this case**, as if to say “we can neither confirm nor deny the existence of this repository.”

That is why you see a "`Not Found`" here.

See [issue 294](https://github.com/github/github-services/issues/294)

> fwiw, I was scratching my head on this same issue trying to debug a hook, and **the solution was to pass basic authentication on the request**.

Comment: Just an observation, that might save someone else a lot of time. When you authenticate, you need to either be the owner, or use a Github Token with *admin:repo_hook* permissions, to even _see_ the hooks, much less add one. An ordinary repo-token won't have enough rights.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to access the API endpoint without authorising (in which case he API will return a 404 response and the JSON error you mentioned). Try passing your credentials with:

```
curl -v -u akonsu https://api.github.com/repos/akonsu/kamyanov-art.com/hooks
```